# Sort by dictionary nested value

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to sort by the `'idx'` value in the following dictionary, to create a list of dictionaries

```
episodes = {
    u '70303660': {
        u 'title': u 'The Forbidden Feast',
        u 'synopsis': u 'Caster and Uryu discuss their views on God, resulting in plans for a horrifying attack -- one that requires everyone else to unite against Caster.',
        u 'summary': {
            u 'notStreaming': False,
            u 'isOriginal': False,
            u 'season': 1,
            u 'idx': 13,
            u '$type': u 'leaf',
            u 'type': u 'episode'
        },
    },
    u '70303654': {
        u 'title': u 'Dark Forest',
        u 'synopsis': u 'The battle is on hold as the group decides what to do about Ryunosuke Uryu and his servant, Caster, who have been kidnapping and sacrificing children.',
        u 'summary': {
            u 'notStreaming': False,
            u 'isOriginal': False,
            u 'season': 1,
            u 'idx': 7,
            u '$type': u 'leaf',
            u 'type': u 'episode'
        },
    },
}
```

So far I have tried:

```
sorted(episodes, lambda x: x['summary']['idx'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over the sub-dictionaries, rather than the episode keys..

```
sorted(episodes.values(), key=lambda x: x['summary']['idx'])
```

(By default, iterating a dictionary directly iterates through its keys, not its values.)

Comment: I get the following exception when trying that: >>> sorted(episodes.values(), key=lambda x: x['summary']['idx'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Oh, sorry, should include `key=`.